# How do I rewrite old URLs without affecting default redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

Let me see if I can explain this.

I used to have `mydomain.com` as my default page. The login page would be `mydomain.com/login` and every content created would become `mydomain.com/topic1`, `mydomain.com/topic2` etc.

But I have created a subdirectory, so it's now `mydomain.com/sub/login` and `mydomain.com/sub/topic1` etc.

I then set `mydomain.com` to redirect to `mydomain.com/sub/login` via my host's panel (Hostinger).

If a user accesses the website from one of the old links, I would like it to change the URL to include the new subdirectory automatically, without affecting the redirect I have created.

How can I do so? Is it possible?

Thanks, folks!

Comment: Kindly do share your htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 to be honest, it's currently empty (the one in the domain's main folder). The redirect is being handled by the host settings I set. But I didn't want to change that, unless I have to. I just wanted to rewrite old URLs in case a user accesses an old link.

Comment: Let's first sort out that "redirect" you have created... So you redirect requests to the host name to your login route? Why that? What if the user is already logged in? The usual approach is to request the default route (whatever that is). And to only jump in and redirect to the login route if no valid session exists.

Comment: And another question that should get answered or better confirmed explicitly by you: so in your new setup you want that `/sub` folder to be visible in the browsers address bar? That is correct?

Comment: @arkascha that's correct!

Comment: So what keeps you from implementing redirection rules for those "old URLs"? I would assume that what you call "host settings" are rules implemented in the actual http server's host configuration. Those will get applied _before_ and directives in distributed configuration files get applied (".htaccess"). So both are not in conflict, unless you create a rewriting loop.

Comment: @arkascha My bad, I had missed your previous question. But yes, I redirect them straight to the login page just because it's easier and it's always been like that. Also, if they're already logged in, my platform automatically redirects them to the appropriate page. And yea, I don't think they conflict. I just don't know what to write in the htaccess file to transform old URLs into new ones, making them functional if a user tries to access an old link (like `mydomain.com/topic1` instead of `mydomain.com/sub/topic1`).

Comment: I fail to see why that approach should be easier, but this is not the topic here.

Comment: You will find literally millions of examples for redirections here on SO and also when using google. I am sure that you will be able to adapt those to your needs. There is little sense in us writing something for you to blindly copy. You need to understand what you implement and this is not rocket science. So I suggest you start out yourself, redirecting one URL after another. If that does not work and you fail to understand why, _then_ is the time to ask for help and to post your own attempt to implement those rules.

Comment: @arkascha my users have basic technological knowledge. Some of them rely on video tutorials, and I don't plan on making them all over again just because the login page isn't showing as default anymore. // I have already tried using other examples, but they don't seem to accomplish what I want. Redirection is working fine. What I can't do is automatically change old URLs, like `/topic1` to `/sub/topic1` in case users try to access old links. I wouldn't have asked it here if I hadn't tried solutions myself, but none of them worked either.

Comment: If you can point to a link or tutorial that accomplishes what I want, I'll gladly try it myself.

Comment: If you tried suggested examples then please show those attempts and explain what changed. Don't get this wrong, I am not trying to push you away. But there already are _millions_ of examples here on SO and out on google for what you ask. Writing another one here will hardly make any difference, if you made several attempts and nothing worked for you. So we need to find out what is wrong with your setup. For that we need to see what you implemented and we need a details description of what effect that had.

Comment: @arkascha I have deleted every piece of code I tested, as I didn't see a point in keeping them in the file. But if you wanna link me another similar question from Stack Overflow, that would work for my case, feel free to post it here, as it would be pretty helpful.